# Digital sign on data

Tags: java, android, digital-signature, dsa

I am trying to sign and verify text using DSA. I have written sample code to sign. But it doesn't work. Can you give a hand with this? This is a only a test because the idea is to sign data, record in a tag an when I read the tag I want to verify the data with the digital sign.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Signature;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText texto;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        texto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.texto);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void test (View v){
        if(v.getId() == R.id.button1)

            firmar(texto.getText().toString());

    }



    public void firmar (String string){
    try{

        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA","SUN");
        SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");

        keyGen.initialize(1024, random);

        KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey priv = pair.getPrivate();
        PublicKey pub = pair.getPublic();


        /* Create a Signature object and initialize it with the private key */

        Signature dsa = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withDSA"); 

        dsa.initSign(priv);

        /* Update and sign the data */

        //String string = texto.getText().toString();
         byte [] bytes = string.getBytes();
         dsa.update(bytes);
         byte[] realSig = dsa.sign();


        AlertDialog.Builder newAlert= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        newAlert.setTitle("Firmado");
        newAlert.show();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            AlertDialog.Builder newAlert= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            newAlert.setTitle("No Firmado");
            newAlert.show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What specifically is failing? Help others to help you by being explicit about the problem you are seeing. Is the code failing to compile? Does some method return unexpected results?

Comment: The compilation is ok but when i put the text and i press the button for signing always appears the message in the exception ("no firmado")